# Amazon S3 bucket :- Item size has exceeded the maximum allowed size

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, updates

I am trying to update an pdf in s3 using nodes
I am getting the following error :

```
Item size has exceeded the maximum allowed size
```

I am not sure what exactly the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Please let me know if I missed any required information

Comment: Please share some further information on how you are uploading the object, code snippet and full stack trace of the exception would help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a wild guess at this answer as you haven't provided much context, but this exception is one typically seen by DynamoDB and not S3.

DynamoDB has a max item size of 400KB and trying to save an item larger than that will produce the exact exception that you shared. Does some part of your upload also rely on DynamoDB?